# Micronaut: Graalvm: Native image tracing agent not working

Tags: java, reflection, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I have been developing MS in Micronaut, which I want to run as Graalvm native image on AWS Lambda. I have few dependencies like Jackson ObjectMapper, Apache POI, etc. in the project which does use reflection framework. But, Graalvm doesn't support reflection framework out of the box. So, we need to provide the configuration for the classes which are using reflection framework. To generate such configuration, I am trying to use Graalvm tracing agent, but it doesn't seems to be working.

- It generates the config JSON files successfully.
- But these config JSONs doesn't contain the classes from 3rd party libs which are added in `build.gradle`.
- I have below parameter in `gradle.properties` file:

  - `org.gradle.jvmargs=-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=<path to dir>`
- Then, I run the project using gradle's `run` task from the IntelliJ, and do execute all the methods which actually use these libs (thus all those libs' code gets executed).
- Once the execution is stopped, I find few config files generated on the dir path mentioned, but those files contains only classes related to Gradle, Jetbrains and few others. I cannot find any classes related to 3rd party libs which I am using and which are mentioned in `build.gradle`.

What should be the correct way to generate the reflection configuration JSON file for Micronaut Graalvm native image?

`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "3.5.1"
}

version = "0.1"
group = "com.base.package"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    orgJsonVersion = "20220320"
    poiVersion = "3.9"
    apacheCommons = "3.12.0"
    googleGson = "2.9.1"
    springValidation = "2.7.3"
    eclipseLink = "3.0.3"
    servletApi = "2.5"
    velocity = "1.7"
    velocityTools = "2.0"
    kafkaClient = "2.1.1"
    googleGuava = "27.0-jre"
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor('io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java')
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-processor")
    annotationProcessor("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-jackson-databind")
    implementation("jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
//    runtimeOnly('org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:2.0.2')
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-hibernate-jpa")
    implementation("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-jdbc-hikari")
    compileOnly("io.micronaut.sql:micronaut-hibernate-jpa")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compileOnly("org.graalvm.nativeimage:svm")

    // compileOnly group: 'io.micronaut', name: 'micronaut-http-server-netty'

    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws")

    implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws-custom-runtime")
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: "${orgJsonVersion}"

    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: "${poiVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: "${poiVersion}"
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: "${apacheCommons}"
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: "${googleGson}"
//    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: "${springValidation}"
    implementation group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'eclipselink', version: "${eclipseLink}"
//    compileOnly group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: "${servletApi}"
    implementation("org.apache.velocity:velocity:${velocity}") {
        exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
    }
    implementation("org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:${velocityTools}") {
        exclude group: 'log4j', module: 'log4j'
    }
    implementation group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka-clients', version: "${kafkaClient}"
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: "${googleGuava}"
//    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.6.9.Final'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-hibernate5', version: '2.8.3'
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.8.3'

}


application {
    mainClass.set("com.base.package.MainApplication")
}

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("11")
}

graalvmNative.toolchainDetection = false
micronaut {
    runtime("lambda_provided")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("com.base.package.*")
    }
}


tasks.named("dockerfileNative") {
    args(
        "-XX:MaximumHeapSizePercent=80",
        "-Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0",
        "-Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=true"
    )
}

graalvmNative.binaries.all {
    buildArgs.add("--no-server -J-Xmx12g -J-Xms4g -O0")
}
```

Comment: You don't want to run the agent on the build VM, you want to run it on the run step. `org.gradle.jvmargs` is for VM arguments for the [build environment](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

Comment: Thanks for responding @JohannesKuhn. How can we run it on run step?

Comment: No idea. I use maven.

Comment: Can you provide your `build.gradle` file? That would help to reproduce setup

Comment: Added `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is something you rarely do I usually run the command directly against the fat jar.

Here is how I do it.

1. Run `./gradlew build`. This creates the fat jar in `builds/libs`
2. Goto `build/libs`
3. Run `java -jar -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=META-INF/native-image <your jar name>-all.jar`

Comment: Tried that, but when I run using `java -jar` command, it exits the application after `No embedded container found. Running as CLI application` (without any error).

Comment: Do we need to add any specific dependency in `build.gradle` to run the Micronaut application from Jar? Currently I have configured this application to run on AWS Lambda as function using Graalvm native image.

Comment: Have added `build.gradle` in the question.

Comment: Thanks @saw303, I just added the netty runtime and then was able to run the jar in local and generate the reflection related configs.

Comment: do you know how can we generate all the reflection configs without running all the possible execution paths in the code. Because I am developing a project which has many 3rd party libs, and executing each and every path will not be possible, because there can be many unseen cases.

Comment: Currently I am specifically talking about Apache POI lib, which has tons of classes and libs with reflection. How can I get all the reflection configs for Apache POI lib? There can be many more such libs in my project.

Comment: Apache POI seems currently causing lots of issues https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2187

I haven't been able yet to get it running as a native image

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri were you able to find out the way to generate all the reflection configs. I am also trying to find out this as there can be various runtime issues which are not known

Comment: @RahulKhanna Unfortunately not. We need to generate reflection configs by executing all the pathways in our code by vising that piece of code somehow. Reflections will not be noted for the code where the executor will not reach.